# Incorrect LocalUserAppDataPath gives Roaming instead of Local/App path in c#

Tags: c#, vb.net

In vb.net I get the path

```
"C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\MyApp\My\1.1.0.0"
```

using:

```
Dim vbPath As [String] = Application.LocalUserAppDataPath
```

In c# I am using:

```
 string csPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
```

but I am getting

```
"C:\\Users\\MyUser\\AppData\\Roaming"
```

I get Roaming instead of local folder, What Am I doing wrong?

Comment: You want `SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData` instead of `SpecialFolder.ApplicationData` I think.

Comment: Also `Application.LocalUserAppDataPath` will work in C# too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a difference between ApplicationData directory and LocalApplicationData directory.

What you want is:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData)
```

> UPDATE:

If you want to know which is the default local application directory then you must use this:

```
Application.LocalUserAppDataPath
```

If you want to customize the directory location then you can do this else:

```
    Dim CustomLocalAppDataPath As String = _
    IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "MyApp\My\1.1.0.0")
```

Comment: What else should I do to get Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData) + \MyApp\My\1.1.0.0 ?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)
```

it represents the system global variable `%AppData%`